# Adding multiple featured images on custom post type with Avada Theme

Tags: custom-post-types, themes, post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I have a custom posttype called "mitglied". I use ACF Pro to add the featured image on the single mitglied custom posttype with _thumbnail_id.

I use the Avada Theme, and Avada supports multiple featured images on posts, pages and portfolio posttype. I want to add this feature to my CPT as well. I tried to safe the image in a custom field on ACF with the Avada key from the second featured image "kd_featured-image-2_post_id". Unfortunately its not working, any ideas?